# Any FileProvider in ASP.NET Core to provide versioned files by folder instead of parameter?

Tags: file, asp.net-core, fileprovider

I need to version my Javacript files (for clearing cache purpose) but cannot use `asp-append-version` because the script files are used from Javascript import:

`import * as Foo from './foo.js'`

Therefore, I plan to have a `FileProvider` that can serve a file with request like `/js/v1.0/app.js` (and so the `foo.js` would be serve from `/js/v1.0/foo.js`). It's okay to serve `/v1.0/js/main.js`, as long as the relative path is maintained.

I tried this:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            RequestPath = "/v*",
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

But it wouldn't work, `RequestPath` does not support wildcard.

Is there a way to do that without a custom Middleware? A FileProvider middleware is quite overkill for this in my opinion. This is my current temporary solution:

```
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseVersionedScripts(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.HasValue &&
                context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/js/v"))
            {
                var filePath = context.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');


                // Write the file to response and return if file exist
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });

        return app;
    }
```

Edit: I think in my case, if FileProvider is not supported, a Controller Action maybe better than middleware because `PhysicalFile` method can take care of the writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a reusable FileProvider that "transforms" (removes) the version path: https://github.com/BibliTech/VersionedFileProvider

```
var versionedFileProvider = new VersionedFileProvider(env.WebRootFileProvider);
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = versionedFileProvider,
});
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

In the end I use an Action to serve the file:

```
[ApiController]
public class FileController : ControllerBase
{

    IHostEnvironment env;
    public FileController(IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("/js/{version}/{**path}")]
    public IActionResult JavascriptFile(string version, string path)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(
            env.ContentRootPath,
            @"wwwroot\js",
            path);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return this.PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/javascript");
        }

        return this.NotFound();
    }

}
```